# Unable to install magento 2

Tags: magento2, installation, setup, mamp

I downloaded magento2 latest version from https://www.mageplaza.com/download-magento/#download.

I pasted the unzipped folder to the htdocs of /Applications/MAMP/ 
When I started the mamp servers and opened magento in the browser, nothing is displayed.

I also tried running these commands

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

I am using mac high sierra

does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: don't know what the problem is, but I have an advice. Never download magento from a third party website. I'm not saying that mageplaza should not be trusted, but the idea is that you don't know what you download unless you get your code from an official place. Github repo or magento website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should download from [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download). After that check your php version like this. [image: php version]

Make sure your command line php version should same as browser php version. For checking command line php version run following command in your command line

```
php -v
```

No need to change permission for MAMP as I know.

*If still not work check using 777 permission of that magento directory for testing.*

Comment: I downloaded from the link you shared, then checked the version of my php but it still wont work.

Comment: Did you checked php -v in your command line?

Comment: yes. its 7.2.11. while the php version used in mamp is 7.2.8

Comment: Now downgrade it to 7.1 or 7.0

Comment: I cant upvote your answer since my rep is below 15

Comment: ok, no worries.